# Android Studio: Android resource linking failed with drawables files

Tags: android

Im currently just setting up a base project in android studio and keep running into this error when I boot up a standard empty activity project. I have not changed anything or added anything just your standard run of the mill project and I cannot resolve this for the life of me. Any ideas?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDkKR.png)

Comment: Have you tried 1st clean build , or second invalidate cache and restart, or delete build folder manually then sync.

Comment: yes, ive tried all of those

Comment: Try one more way commenting your dependency one by one so that you find what causing it actually.